# Excel not recognizing formula

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to add a formula to a cell and it works, but when i try to enter the exact same fomula in the next cell it doesn't recognise it and values a false.  It's the exact same formula with just one letter changed.  For example here is the formula
=IF('SAF,Carrier,National Accts'!F4="c",SUM('SAF,Carrier,National Accts'!D4))
then in the next column i just want to insert an "s" instead of a "c". It has worked in the past, but for some reason it isn't working now. when the value "c' is chosen the formula works, but not with the "s" value.

Please help. thank you

Answer (score 0):

IF takes a third parameter, which is the value if condition is false.  I assume you'll want a 0.

```
=IF('SAF,Carrier,National Accts'!F4="c",SUM('SAF,Carrier,National Accts'!D4), 0)
```